# Trouble invoking a javascript event

Tags: javascript, events, element

I'm taking an online course in JS and I'm having trouble understanding this assignment.

I want to create (with JavaScript) a button (with an `input`-element with the `type`-value `button`) and to add (with JavaScript) the button in the web document, for example using the function `document.body.appendChild`. I also want to make that an alert-dialogbox appears when you click on the button, and all HTML-contents must be created using JavaScript.

This is my code so far and it's pretty useless...

```
function myFunction() {
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");   // Create a <button> element
btn.innerHTML = "CLICK ME";                   // Insert text
btn.onclick = function(){                     // Assign a function to execute on the click event of the button
  alert("Hello World");                       // Prompt the Alert 
}
document.body.appendChild(btn);               // Append <button> to <body>
```